# XML not exist when it does

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I am new to Intellij Idea and trying to follow some tutorials. I tried to load an XML into `"new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext()"`. However, there is an error which stated `FileNotFoundException`.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [vehicle_beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
class path resource [vehicle_beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

This is my structure:

[image]

Here is my code:

[image]

Comment: For future reference, please [don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6395627).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML File location is problem here. As you are using Maven for project, create another folder at level of java named "resources" and put your XML file inside it.

`src/main/resources`

Resources folder should contain all the config related files to make them available for application to consume. Otherwise you have to pass the full file path to your file reader.

Answer (score 0):

please try this FileSystemXmlApplicationContext instead of ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

private static final ApplicationContext ac =
    new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(
        "src/main/java/org/example/vehicle_beans.xml"
    );

hope it will work for you